# How do I batch extract metadata from DM3 files using ImageJ?

Tags: imagej

How can you extract metadata for a batch of images? My first thought was to record a macro and then modify it to operate on a list of file names.

In that vein, I tried recording a macro doing something like this:

<kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd>              `# Open a file`
 
12.dm3<kbd>Enter</kbd>         `# Select file to open`
<kbd>Ctrl-i</kbd>              `# Open metadata in a new window`
<kbd>Ctrl-s</kbd>              `# Save file`
Info for 12.txt<kbd>Enter</kbd>`# Name of file being saved` 
<kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd>`# Close current window` 
<kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd>`# Close current window`

These steps work when I do them manually. This results in the following macro, which seems to be missing most of what I tried to record:

```
open("/path/to/file/12.dm3");
run("Show Info...");
run("Close");
run("Close");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying a [Jython script that is supposed to extract dimension metadata from an image](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fiji-devel/RHITjw1kYO4):

```
from java.io import File
from loci.formats import ImageReader
from loci.formats import MetadataTools

import glob

# Create output file
outFile = open('./pixel_sizes.txt','w')

# Get list of DM3 files
filenames = glob.glob('*.dm3')

for filename in filenames:

        # Open file
        file = File('.', filename)

        # parse file header
        imageReader = ImageReader()
        meta = MetadataTools.createOMEXMLMetadata()
        imageReader.setMetadataStore(meta)
        imageReader.setId(file.getAbsolutePath())

        # get pixel size
        pSizeX = meta.getPixelsPhysicalSizeX(0)

        # close the image reader
        imageReader.close()

        outFile.write(filename + "\t" + str(pSizeX) + "\n")

# Close the output file
outFile.close()
```

([Gist](https://gist.github.com/molecules/7572351)).

Comment: See also http://openmicroscopy.org/site/support/bio-formats4/users/imagej/ for more examples of how to use Bio-Formats in an ImageJ macro.

Answer (score 1):

You could use getImageInfo() instead of run("Show Info..."). This will create a string in the macro containing the run("Show Info...") output, but can then be modified as you like. See http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#getImageInfo for more information.

Comment: The proposed usage of getImageInfo() in Jython for an ImagePlus `imp` reads `from ij.plugin import ImageInfo;       StringWithImageInfo = ImageInfo().getImageInfo(imp) `